# Loopback: How to copy files from one container to another?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm using `Strongloop loopback` for my backend API. 
I'm using it's `loopback-component-storage` to upload and manage files. More specifically, I'm using the file system for the moment but will switch to AWS storage once on production.

The users on the platform can copy a project and therefor will also copy the linked files that have been uploaded.

My question is, **How can I copy files from one container to another?**

Here's my code so far to create a new container:

```
    Project.app.models.storage.getContainer(templateId, function (err, container) {
    if(err){
        // If error, no docs have been added or created, so just skip                        
        return;
    }
    Project.app.models.storage.createContainer({ name: projectId},function (err,container) {
    if(err){
       console.log("Error creating a container when copying project");
       return;
    }
    // Here is where I need assistance
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to create download stream then pipe it to upload stream from one container to another, but that would not be a good idea since you will create unnecessary traffic. Let your underlying environment do the job for you.

On your local development environment you can use fs module to work with files, but when you migrate your storage to S3 you should use [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) to copy files. You can create remote method on your Storage model that will take source bucket/folder and destination bucket/folder to copy files for you.

Something like:

```
  Storage.remoteMethod(
    'copyS3File',
    {
      accepts: [
        {arg: 'copySource', type: 'string'},
        {arg: 'destinationBucket', type: 'string'},
        {arg: 'destinationFileName', type: 'string'}],
      returns: {arg: 'success', type: 'string'}
    }
  );

  Storage.copyS3File = function(copySource, destinationBucket, destinationFileName, cb) {
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var s3 = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'yourbucket',region:'yourregion'}});
    var params = {CopySource: copySource, Bucket: destinationBucket, Key: destinationFileName};
    s3.copyObject(params, function(err, success) {
      if (err) cb(err); // an error occurred
      else     cb(null, success)           // successful response
    });
  });
```

See [Calling the copyObject operation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) on S3.

Please note that this code is not tested or ready for production. It is here only to give you an idea how to do it.

Also note that S3 is somewhat different than loopbackjs implementation of storage. S3 has flat structure but organizing files in folders is supported using key name prefixes.

[Working with S3 folders](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html)

To make things more clear, you can retrieve file list from your source container and loop through that list to copy files to new destination using remote method created above like:

```
Storage.getFiles({container: 'yourContainer'}, function(files){

  files.forEach(function(file){
    Storage.copyS3File(file.container + '/' + file.name, 'newContainer', 'newFile.name', cb);
  });

}, function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An idea to do this for filesystem provider

1. Get list of Files from the container from which you want to copy the files using storage.GetFiles('container-name',callback)
2. Create the container in which you want to copy these files using storage. createContainer()
3. Get a stream for uploading using storage.uploadStream('recently-   created-container', 'file-name')
4. Obtain read stream to the file and pipe the read and write operations
5. repeat step 3 and step 4 for each file (or you can chain the streams if you want)

In your case code will look like

```
Project.app.models.storage.getContainer(templateId, function (err, container) {
    if(err || !container){
        // If error, no docs have been added or created, so just skip
        return;
    }
    Project.app.models.storage.getFiles(templateId, function (err, files) {
        if(err){
            // If error, no docs have been added or created, so just skip
            return;
        }
      Project.app.models.storage.createContainer({ name: projectId},function (err,newcontainer) {
        if(err || !newcontainer){
           console.log("Error creating a container when copying project");
           return;
         }
         files.forEach(function(file){
           var writer = container.uploadStream(newcontainer.name, file.name);
            require('fs').createReadStream('path-to-storage-directory/'+container.name+'/'+file.name).pipe(writer);
            writer.on('finish', function(err,done){
              console.log('finished writing file'+file.name)
            });
            writer.on('error', function(err){
              console.log('error in copying file'+file.name,err)
            });
         });
      });
  })
})
```